# Module has no exported member - Typescript

Tags: typescript, import

I'm using typescript for a personal project, and I'm trying to import a function from a library [Solid Client JS](https://github.com/inrupt/solid-client-js)

The thing is, I created a single file.ts and did

```
import { getFile } from '@inrupt/solid-client";
```

NOTHING more than that.... and I run "tsc"

It return the error:

```
❯ tsc
node_modules/@inrupt/solid-client/dist/rdf.internal.d.ts:24:10 - error TS2305: Module '"./datatypes"' has no exported member 'XmlSchemaTypeIri'.

24 import { XmlSchemaTypeIri } from "./datatypes";
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

I think it's happening because of my `tsconfig.json`, it looks like this:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2015",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Does anyone had the same problem before?

Answer (score 1):

I simply added `"skipLibCheck": true` on my tsconfig.json.
It's solved :)

Comment: You saved my day, good sir! Had this problem when running `tsc` to build a an npm package